# Nice notation for projection maps

Tags: soft-question, notation, category-theory

Let $X\times Y$ be a product of two object of a category, and consider the natural projections
$$ X\times Y \to X \quad\text{ and }\quad X\times Y \to Y. $$
Usually I denote them by $\pi_X$ and $\pi_Y$, but the subscript are often annoying to carry over all the times, so sometimes I go for $\pi$ and $\rho$.

Just for the sake of curiosity, what kind of notation do you use for such a situation?

Comment: $p_{1}$ and $p_{2}$ if the context allows it.

Comment: If the codomain is clear by context, you could (by abuse of notation) just write $\pi$ for both maps...

Comment: Your notation $\pi_X$ and $\pi_Y$ is optimal because it is so explicit . If you want very simple notation, you might try  $p$ and $q$, so that you don't have Greek letters either.

Comment: Some people use pr$_X$ and pr$_Y$, and in$_X$ for the natural injections into the coproduct.

Comment: People, please make your comments to (CW) answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some options are

- $p_X$ and $p_Y$
- $\mathrm{pr}_X$ and $\mathrm{pr}_Y$
- $\pi_X$ and $\pi_Y$
- $p$ and $q$
  $\vdots$

if the factors are $X$ and $Y$.

However, if you the factors are indexed by some set, for example $X_i$ with $i\in\{1,2\}$, one should use the same index for the projections, i.e. $p_i$.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$; sometimes $\pi$ and $\pi'$ if the subscripts interfere with some other subscripts.